# Заголовок ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

В ViewPager 12 страниц, 6 из них называются, к примеру, "123", другие 6 называются "АБВ".
Сначала идут все 6 страниц "123", потом остальные 6 "АБВ" страниц.
Хочу, чтобы при перелистывании 1-5 страниц сверху было написано "123" и только при перелистывании с 6 страницы на 7 надпись плавно менялась на "АБВ" и наоборот, а при перелистывании других страниц, надписи оставались неподвижными.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Нужно получить плавную смену названий "123" и "АБВ", которая перемещается как бы вместе с 6 страницей на 7ую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо вынести вашу надпись за пределы ViewPager. Например поместив ViewPager и TextView с надписью во FrameLayout. Так у вас надпись не будет листаться вместе со страницами ViewPager. Менять же саму надпись вы можете в колбэке слушателя смены страниц ViewPager - OnPageChangeListener